# JSON object doesn't contain class name

Tags: json, jax-rs

I used Netbeans IDE 7.1.2 TO create RESTFUL Webservices from database. I've tested the GET/SET methods using the IDE's **Test RESTful Web Services** context menu.The thing is, the output from **application/json** format doesn't contain name of the class. It just gives me an array of objects with their respective value of instance fields. 
Here is what I'm getting

```
[{"id":1129,"salary":4212,"numberOfCars":9},{"id":3300,"salary":101,"numberOfCars":6},
{"id":3323,"salary":315,"numberOfCars":5},{"id":8983,"salary":756,"numberOfCars":1},
{"id":23422,"salary":537,"numberOfCars":2}]
```

The name of this class is Customer and I'm trying to parse this JSON data in Android app but without the class's name to iterate over, I'm lost.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, exactly as JSON standard wants it. What are you trying to do? Why are you lost? What is your relevant Android code?

Comment: I'm trying to get the objects from the Server and display it on a ListView in my Android code. The JSON parsers that I saw so far use that class name to parse the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all of the parsers that I have seen, the class name is never *inside* the JSON. You have to know what the JSON contains before you go and parse it. For example, GSON (off the top of my head):

```
class Dude {
  int id;
  int salary;
  int numberOfCars;
}

Dude[] dudez = gson.fromJson(json, Dude[].class);
```

Comment: For me to say Dude[].class, the class Dude need to be defined in the client as well. I have a feeling that is not right; or is it?

Comment: It does not matter how you generate your JSON. You can read JSON from static text file, you can print it out from JavaScript ad-hoc, you can generate it with another Java library, like Jackson for example, with `Map<String, int>` instead of `Dude`... whatever the source, the above can read it.